# Ubuntu one files, deleting pictures from pc should remove them from phones gallery

Tags: ubuntu-one, files, phone

When im using the ubuntu one android phone app for files which will automatically upload my pictures taken to the cloud and then to my desktop, if i delete them from my desktop then they should be removed from the phones gallery

Answer (score 3):

I'm a Software Developer at Canonical, author of Ubuntu One Files.

We have this feature on our TODO list as it has also been requested by other users via support email. Thus, we plan to implement this in Ubuntu One Files, stay tuned.

Comment: This was removed by mistake! Sorry for the trouble

Comment: That's OK :) I'm not much familiar with these systems, but I think you can mark it as accepted Answer, if it has addressed your post :) Thanks and have a great day.

Comment: It's not my question, so I can't - the original author will need to so

Comment: Yup, I mistook you for the author :)